# How to apply stripslashes() to all form elements prior to output with Zend_Form

Tags: php, zend-framework

How do I apply stripslashes() to all form elements prior to output with Zend_Form?

I have tried:

```
//the filter
class lib_filters_Stripslashes implements Zend_Filter_Interface{
    public function filter($value){
        return stripslashes($value);
    }
}
...
...
...

//In the form
$form->setElementFilters(array(new lib_filters_Stripslashes));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
array_map('stripslashes', $_POST)
```

Comment: What does trimming have to do with stripping slashes?

Answer (score 3):

If you find that you need to `stripslashes` on all fields, most likely, your web host is configured to run with the deprecated [magic-quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) setting turned on. If you are able, I would recommend that you turn it off instead.

Comment: The best suggestion yet! I also wouldn't fix some obscure issue, but instead get to the root of it.